# spark.write.synapsesql options with Azure Synapse Spark Pool

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Within Azure Synapse, I am using the synapsesql function with the Scala language within a Spark Pool notebook to push the contents of a data frame into the SQL Pool

```
// Write data frame to sql table
df2.write.
option(Constants.SERVER,s"${pServerName}.sql.azuresynapse.net").
synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.xtr.${pTableName}",Constants.INTERNAL)
```

This works successfully, however I would like to add some extra functionality

1. How do I specify the index type to be HEAP instead of Clustered Column store Index. In Data Bricks it can be done through .option("tableOptions","heap,distribution=ROUND-ROBIN") however this doesn't work in the Spark Pool notebook.
2. How do I overwrite the table in the SQL Pool if it already exists?
   In Data Bricks you have SaveAsTable but I can't find anything similar in the Spark pool notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, as per this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/optimize-data-warehouse-query-performance-azure-synapse-analytics/5-use-indexes-to-improve),

> When a table is created, by default the data structure has no indexes
> and is called a heap.

To use the HEAP type index, while creating the table simply specify HEAP in the WITH clause:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
  (  
    id int NOT NULL,  
    lastName varchar(20),  
    zipCode varchar(6)  
  )  
WITH ( HEAP );
```

To overwrite,  import `org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode` Class in your SQL Notebook and use `Overwrite` mode.

> Overwrite mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if
> data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be overwritten
> by the contents of the DataFrame.

Refer [DataFrame write SaveMode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#dataframe-write-savemode-support) to know more.

Also check this [given example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#write-using-basic-authentication) for your reference.

Comment: The overwrite command works perfect now. I was missing the import statement: org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode 

Using the overwrite command looks to use the existing index type i.e HEAP if the table already exists which is good. However if the table doesn't exist it still creates it with a clustered column store index. Is there a way to force it to be heap if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can create a HEAP index table by using below code:
CREATE TABLE myTable
  (  
    id int NOT NULL,  
    lastName varchar(20),  
    zipCode varchar(6)  
  )  
WITH ( HEAP );
refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-index

Comment: I want to create it as part of the Scala code in the notebook when pushing data into Synapse, not in the SQL code. Creating it in the SQL code means if a new column is added then the notebook will fail as the columns differ to the data frame.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in scala. Generally we implement indexing in SQL code only while creating the table.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working using your advice.

Comment: hi @UtkarshPal, oneQuery here as i am new to this Tech, i have a same issue, i have done my transformations in synapse notebooks but now i want to load all the data in dedicated pool from my spark pool, do i need to create a same schema in the dedicated pool table before loading the data from my notebbok